# Css div selector multiple classes

Tags: html, css

I am working on a wordpress theme and I have a this code in HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid mytheme-container" >
        <div class="container-fluid col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-7 404page"> 
                    <p id="404">404</p>
                    <p id="page-not-found">Page not found... :(</p>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

I want to add height to the last div and I thought my css in this way:

```
body > div.container-fluid.mytheme-container > div.container-fluid.col-lg-offset-5.col-lg-7.404page {
    height: 100vmin;
}
```

That doesn't work, just if I let the selector like this:

```
body > div.container-fluid.mytheme-container > div {

}
```

But I think that this will apply to every child of mytheme-container  and I don't want that. So, how can I get the selector for that div ( 404page ) in a more specific way than the last one?

Comment: provide us link for your site, if it is live

Comment: why don't you add a new class to your div and define a style for it?

Comment: It is not live, it is made on my pc with XAMPP.

Comment: It seems a good idea, but I would like to know how to compose that selector :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes and IDs should not start with numbers. While it's possible to make them work, it's a hassle and kind of goes against the spirit of "identifiers" in every other programming language anyway.

Best to keep to the more-or-less global definition of "identifier", and use `page-404` or similar - besides, that's more consistent with your other classes `container-fluid`, `col-lg-offset-5` and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've changed my class with "page-404" and now it is working :D

Comment: @CristiCazan I'd also like to point out that basing selectors on "generic" things like `col-lg-offset-5` is a generally bad idea, because what if you want to change the design slightly and make that a `col-lg-offset-4` instead? You'd be best off just defining a style for `.page-404` alone.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the class '404page'.  class names shouldn't begin with a number.

If you can you should change the class name to 'page404' or something similar,  if not, I think you can still work with the other classes as selectors (without 404page).

See working example here:

```css
body > div.container-fluid.mytheme-container >  div.container-fluid.col-lg-offset-5.col-lg-7 {
    color:red;
}
//same, but without the 404page class
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid mytheme-container" >
        <div class="container-fluid col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-7 404page"> 
                    <p id="404">404</p>
                    <p id="page-not-found">Page not found... :(</p>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want apply css to last div, flow this code.

```
body > div.container-fluid.mytheme-container > div:last-child {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can have classes starting with digits and selectors for them, but you have to escape digits for selector. Also it's possible to add other characters (e.g. `!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `{`, `|`, `}`, and `~`) but they need to be escaped. Here is demo

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

/* escaped selector */
#\34 04 {
  border: 5px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="404"></div>
```

More info about [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes). Also [CSS escaping online](https://mothereff.in/css-escapes).

---

But of cource this doesn't look maintainable and I would recommend you to consider changing you identifiers starting with letter (or at least hyphen or underscore).

Answer (score 0):

> you Should not start class with number.if insert a litter with first `404page` like `a404page` your code works.

```css
body > div.container-fluid.mytheme-container > div.container-fluid.col-lg-offset-5.col-lg-7.a404page {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container-fluid mytheme-container" >
        <div class="container-fluid col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-7 a404page"> 
                    <p id="404">404</p>
                    <p id="page-not-found">Page not found... :(</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```